# get Bitmap from URL with cyrillic

Tags: android, url, bitmap

I want to get a Bitmap from URL my code is:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        //testBitMap = myBitmap;
        Log.d("myLogs", "return Bitmap");
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        return null;
    }
}
```

But when I cannot get Bitmap when I put url with cyrillic `http://cl228041.tmweb.ru/sites/default/files/бмв_0.jpg`
I try:

```
URLEncoder.encode(yourString, HTTP.UTF-8);
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Are you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
        url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        URL imageUrl = new URL(new URI(url).toASCIIString());
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
```